# How to shows notification on vaadin component

Tags: button, notifications, components, vaadin, vaadin7

Can anyone please help me.

I need to show the **notification number** on button. Like we see on Facebook or vaadin forms just like show below.

I have searched a lot but I didn't get satisfied anuswer. 
[image]

Thanks in advance. 
Pankaj

Comment: Unfortunately, the Overlays add on is not supported for Vaadin 7 (https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/overlays). It would fit your needs.

Comment: This notification is often referred to as "badging"

Answer (score 5):

In button caption you can inject custom html.

On example in [Vaadin valo theme demo](https://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!buttons-and-links) you can see links in the left menu: [image]

The number is in button caption included with the code:

```
b.setCaption(b.getCaption() + " <span class=\"valo-menu-badge\">123</span>");
```

See the complete code on [github](https://github.com/vaadin/valo-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/tests/themes/valo/ValoThemeUI.java).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I think I have not explained my question correctly. I am having a button with caption. Now I need to show some number on this button. Like news feed. For example If 5 notifications are there then 5.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i explained to you.

Comment: Just see my edited post. I have added one screenshot. Just like this I need need. But in that example different style of buttons are there.

Comment: On the picture I posted, in the last row you can see button with text "Text Fields" and on the right side is the notification with number "123". All what you need to do is to tune css and you will get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Is very later, but well, if you use vaadin dashboard just have to modify the file common.css

```
.valo-menu .valo-menu-badge,
  /*.dashboard-view */.notifications.unread .v-button-caption {
    @include valo-badge-style;
    position: absolute;
    right: round($v-unit-size/3);
    font-size: round($v-font-size * 0.9);
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  /* .dashboard-view */.notifications.unread .v-button-caption {
    display: block;
    top: round($v-unit-size / -5);
    right: round($v-unit-size / -5);
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
  }
```

If not add it to your styles.css

Always Remove annotated code blocks (/**/)

Now, in the Button:

```
b.addStyleName("notifications");
b.addStyleName("unread");
b.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_ICON_ONLY);
b.setCaption("7"); //any number, count, etc
```

See NotificationsButton in [DashboardView](https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo/blob/7.7/src/main/java/com/vaadin/demo/dashboard/view/dashboard/DashboardView.java)